# Error: Attempt to redefine node in linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian, rjags

I have fitted following `simple linear regression` `Bayesian` model using `rjags`.
I was able to run the model by specifying all the predictors separately(like for a `lm` object). Now I want to learn how to specify the predictors by introducing them as a matrix instead of specifying them separately.

So I ran the following code, but it gave some errors.

I used `tobbaco` data set in `rrr` package to provide a reproducible example.

```
library(rrr)
require(dplyr)
library(rjags)
tobacco <- as_data_frame(tobacco)
N1 = length(tobacco$Y1.BurnRate)
x1 = model.matrix(Y1.BurnRate~X2.PercentChlorine+X3.PercentPotassium ,data = tobacco)
        
bayes_model_mul1=
 "model {
      for(i in 1:N1){
        Y1.BurnRate[i]~dnorm(mu1[i],tau1)
        
        for(j in 1:3){
          mu1[i]=beta1[j]*x1[i,j]  
        }
      }
      
      for (l in 1:3) { beta1[l] ~dnorm(0, 0.001) }        
      tau1 ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
      sigma_tau1 = 1/tau1 
        
    }"
        
        
model3 <- jags.model(textConnection(bayes_model_mul1), 
                     data = list(Y1.BurnRate=tobacco$Y1.BurnRate, x1=x1, N1=N1),
                     n.chains=1)
```

After I run `model3` , I got following error.

> Error in jags.model(textConnection(bayes_model_mul1), data =   list(Y1.BurnRate = tobacco$Y1.BurnRate,  :
> RUNTIME ERROR:
> Compilation error on line 6.
> Attempt to redefine node mu1[1]

Can anyone help me figure this out ?
Does this due to introducing predictors as a matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, here are two:

1. Use matrix multiplication outside of the likelihood loop

```
m1 =
 "model {
     mu1 = x1 %*% beta1 # ---> this
     for(i in 1:N1){
       Y1.BurnRate[i] ~ dnorm(mu1[i], tau1)
    }

    for (l in 1:3) { beta1[l] ~ dnorm(0, 0.001) }
    tau1 ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
    sigma_tau1 = 1/tau1 
 }"
```

2. Use `inprod` to multiply the parameters with the design matrix

```
m2 = 
  "model {
    for(i in 1:N1){
      mu1[i] = inprod(beta1, x1[i,]) #----> this
      Y1.BurnRate[i] ~ dnorm(mu1[i], tau1)
    }

    for (l in 1:3) { beta1[l] ~ dnorm(0, 0.001) }
    tau1 ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
    sigma_tau1 = 1/tau1 
 }"
```

---

You received an error with `for(j in 1:3){ mu1[i] = beta1[j]* x1[i,j] }` as every time you loop though the parameter index `j` you overwrite `mu1[i]`. It also doesn't sum up the individual terms. You may be able to index `mu1` with `j` as well and then `sum` but untested ...

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your answer. I have another question and it is great  if you can give a comment on that too. After getting MCMC samples, from the above code, I am getting following warning message "Warning message:got this warning previously also for  different Bayesian models . So I am curious about this.  Will you be able to give a comment on that too ?

Comment: Hi @student_R123; what is the warning message please? And what code generates it?

Comment: Hi, Thank again. The warning message was "Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : start value not changed".  However I am not getting it now. Earlier I got this  when I extract MCMC samples (model3 <- jags.model(textConnection(bayes_model_mul1), data = list(Y1.BurnRate=tobacco$Y1.BurnRate, x1=x1, N1=N1),
                     n.chains=1)
params <- c('beta1','sigma_tau1')
samps.1 <- coda.samples(model3, params, n.iter = 10000)
burn.in=1000
summary.model.1=summary(window(samps.1, start = burn.in))) . But in past I got this error couple of times for different models.

Comment: Thanks. That's from the `window` function. If you rerun `coda.samples` without running `jags.model` again you can get this warning / sometimes an error. Ie never looked into it much and just rerun `jags.model`

Comment: ... if you look at `str(samps.1)` you will see an attribute `attr(samps.1[[1]], "mcpar")` which gets incremented very time you run `coda.samples` without rerunning `jags.model`. This throws out the `start` and `end` times for the `window` function, I'm not sure why this value get incremented ... it could be updating the model and starting from the end of the previous run??

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Honestly, I dont have any idea about this. I am learning Bayesian from the scratch .